# R - Understanding pipes and the magrittr syntax

Tags: r, subset, magrittr

I am trying out pipes and the magrittr package.
Although it seems somewhat easy to understand, I have a hard time understanding how to write conditional subsetting with pipes.

For a dataset, you can use 'filter' function and others but it gets  unclear for a vector (at least to me).

For example, if I want to subset values greater than 2, how am I supposed to do that?
I know there is the aliases available but they did something funky yesterday.

**I'd like to understand how to write my pipes using `[`and `<`for example but also using the aliases.**
Can you provide me with some examples and compare the two syntax?
Like

1) subsetting of a vector and retrieving values greater/lower than 2

2) how to combine two logical expressions (that I would normally do with & or |...)

```
Num1 <- 
DataSet$myvariable %>% 
strsplit(split = " ") %>% 
lengths() %>% is_less_than(2) %>% #subset?
```

How to extract the values when I have my TRUE and FALSE?

Thanks a lot

Comment: use `%>% extract(Dataset, .)`

Comment: You could use `purrr::keep`

Comment: I don't think I can use extract there. @akrun
The output of lengths is a vector of length of elements in a list.
If I understood correctly, the dot "." corresponds to the output of the step before, right?

What if I want to use this output of this previous step (let's say it is the index of something) to subset in the first dataset. Should I make a new pipeline or can I do it in the same pipeline and refer to the original dataset?

Comment: I think I got it! At least for the syntax!
First what I was missing were parenthesis:
    `is_less_than(2) is equivalent to <(2)  (with the little signs on the side sides of the operator) `

Answer (score 1):

To subset a vector with a condition, you can do the following:

```
library(magrittr)

1:10 %>%  `<`(5) %>%  `[`(1:10,.)
```

or:

```
1:10 %>% `<`(5) %>% (1:10)[.]
# [1] 1 2 3 4
```

These are equivalent to:

```
(1:10)[1:10 < 5]
```

The reason I am placing the `.` after `1:10` in `[`(1:10,.), but placing it (implicitly) before `5` in `<`(5) is because for the latter, I am feeding in the vector `1:10`, whereas for the former, I am feeding in the *condition* from `1:10 < 5`.

To subset a dataset with a condition from a vector:

```
mtcars$cyl %>% `<`(5) %>% `[`(mtcars, ., )
```

or:

```
mtcars$cyl %>% `<`(5) %>% mtcars[.,]
```

These are equivalent to:

```
mtcars[mtcars$cyl < 5,]
```

The extra comma in `[`(mtcars, ., ) is needed because you are subsetting dataframes intead of vectors, just like the difference between `(1:10)[1:10 < 5]` and `mtcars[mtcars$cyl < 5,]`

**Result:**

```
                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
Volvo 142E     21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

Comment: Or `1:10 %>% '['(.<5)`

Answer (score 0):

I think I found partly the answer to my questions.

First for the syntax:

```
%>% is_less_than(2) #would be equivalent to
%>% `<`(2) # I didn't know about the parenthesis here
```

If there exists a more detailed documentation about magrittr with many examples, I would be happy to know about it.

Second, concerning the subset, it could be written as such:

```
AssignData <- Vector %>%
purrr::keep(., `<`(., 2))
```

AND FURTHER

```
AssignData <- DATASET %$% SOME OPERATIONS THAT GIVES A VECTOR (split?) %>%
`<`(2) %>% 
which %>%
DATASET[.,]
```

To extract something from the dataset based on some criterias in the vector.

Comment: `1:10 %>% extract(is_less_than(., 4))` works fine with magrittr only. Btw, without real example data, it's very hard to follow what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Frank I am working on ecological data. I have this data set that contains species names and I am updating those names.
I first split the names to select genus and species seperately. Some names are not species names ("Fish") and when you split them, the elements in the list are of length 1 (instead of for instance 2 with "Canis" "lupus").
I first split and then select the length 1 to explore what I get and what I can eliminate or update.
So basically, I convert strings into a numerical value and deal with those values (i.e. in how many parts I can split the original species name).

Comment: Ok. For that, I would use a data.frame, not just a vector: `DF = data.frame(nm = c("Fish", "Canis lupus"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE); DF$nm_vec = strsplit(DF$nm, " "); DF$nm_len = lengths(DF$nm_vec)`. Then you could do `with(DF, Map(nm_vec, nm_len, f = function(vec, len) if (len==1) "yo" else if (len == 2) "no"))` where f is a function with if-else conditions to handle each length differently.

Comment: I'll try that! Thanks!